# Hide and show list items of divs after nth item of direct child only

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Say I have an unordered list, like so:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mgobinath30/63bkkmbf/9/)

**HTML Code :**

```
<ul>
  <li>One
  <ul>
  <li>on 1.1</li>
  <li>on 1.2</li>
  <li>on 1.3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>One 1</li>
  <li>Two 2</li>
  <li>Three 3</li>
  <li>Four 4</li>
  <li>Five 5</li>
  <li>One 11</li>
  <li>Two 22</li>
  <li>Three 33</li>
  <li>Four 44</li>
  <li>Five 55</li>
</ul>
<span class="show_more">see more</span>
```

**Script File :**

```
$('.nav_accordian').each(function(){
    var max = 4
    if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><span class="show_more">(see more)</span></li>');

        $('.sub_accordian').click( function(){
            $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle();

            if ( $('.show_more').length ) {
                $(this).html('<span class="showMore">show More</span>');
            } 
            else {
                $(this).html('<span class="showMore">less More</span>');
            };
        });
    };
});
```

i did for when i click on 'show more' it should be visible next five results of list items . Once every results loaded 'show more' text would be changed on 'less more'.

and when i clicked upon the 'less more' button first results result items should be visible other items would be hide.

The issue is the script is consider child list of li also

Comment: "Less more" is not a good name.  "Show less" might be.

Comment: @isherwood: i want show first 5 list items but my was consider as all the <li> child list also

Answer (score 1):

Giving a class to the list element you want to count on should resolve your problem :

```
<ul>
  <li class="list__element">One
  <ul>
  <li>on 1.1</li>
  <li>on 1.2</li>
  <li>on 1.3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__element">Two</li>
  <li class="list__element">Three</li>
  <li class="list__element">Four</li>
  <li class="list__element">Five</li>
  <li class="list__element">One 1</li>
  <li class="list__element">Two 2</li>
  <li class="list__element">Three 3</li>
  <li class="list__element">Four 4</li>
  <li class="list__element">Five 5</li>
  <li class="list__element">One 11</li>
  <li class="list__element">Two 22</li>
  <li class="list__element">Three 33</li>
  <li class="list__element">Four 44</li>
  <li class="list__element">Five 55</li>
</ul>
<span class="show_more">see more</span>
```

And in your JS you would count then ".list__element", like so :

```
if ($(this).find('.list__element').length > max) {
...
}
```

Comment: Also, your script file in your [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mgobinath30/63bkkmbf/7/) does really not look like what your wrote in your question

Comment: There's really no need for a class. Use `children()` rather than `find()`.

Comment: I have had trouble with the children() function as he counted the sub-children too... Never found why.